# Add values to complex array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a modules array for my software, and I need to know how I would add to the array through PHP without the user having to directly add it (i.e. automated). I can do this with a simple array that looks like this:

```
$array = array( 'key'=>'value' );
```

however, my array looks like this:

```
$modules = array('Forums'=>array('file'=>)...
```

So, how could I add values to the array with a PHP function where say, a user clicks a button to add a new module, and all it asks for is the name of the module and the filename?

```
foreach($modules as $name => $module) if ($module['enabled']) {
    require_once('include/scripts/'.$module['file']);
}
```

If the above were used to load the module, would @Darren's comment still apply?

Comment: Instead of downvoting and then leaving _without even contributing_ maybe you should be required to give a reason that the OP can see for downvoting.

Comment: `$modules[] = array('MODULE_NAME' => array('file' => '',.....));`. You'd just add it as a new element? or even `$modules['MODULE_NAME'] = array(....`

Comment: @Darren Can you look at my edit, please?

Comment: "Instead of downvoting and then leaving without even contributing maybe you should be required to give a reason that the OP can see for downvoting" -5 downvotes should tell you a story, really. It's maybe time to have a read of the help section, there's a bit about "what can I ask".   If downvoters had to comment just to tell you why, you'd just get generic responses which would not help at all "Do not agree" "Poor question"

Comment: @James You can stop people from giving generic reasons. It's actually not hard in the slightest. That's not the point. I searched for it myself before, and didn't find an answer. Please do not make assumptions of what I may or may not have done before coming here.

Comment: @James, At the time, the only word that I could think of was "complex". Once again, it's really not hard with a simple function that checks for the amount of characters, combined with checking for generic reasons like, "Bad question", or "I don't agree". Now that we have checked for this, we can check other downvote history from the user, and see if this downvote may be spam.

Comment: @James I see what you're saying now. I'll take a look at it in a bit and see if I feel that it would be worth getting involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I commented is how to do it. I assume you're storing this array in a cache/session where it's semi-persistent right? What you want to do is append the item to the array. Say your array looks like this:

```
$modules = array(
    'Forums' => array('file' => 'link/to/file.php', 'enabled' => TRUE),
    .....etc
);
```

All you need to do is add it to the array:

```
$modules['Example_Module'] = array('file' => 'link/to/this/module', 'enabled' => TRUE);
```

Which will allow you to continue using that include code block you have.

See this: [**Example**](https://eval.in/303071)

It sticks to the structure you require.